# How to use the React Context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a React App (setup with CRA) with a global element (custom cursor, that is a rounded div following the mouse) whose style I want to update/change when hovering various other components that are nested differently and more or less deeply (in the structure provided below I am only listing one example component). From what I understand this is a good use case for Context API.

The structure of my App looks like this (simplified):

```
<Cursor />
<Layout>
  <Content>
    <Item />
  </Content>
</Layout>
```

So when hovering `<Item />` (amongst other components) I want to update the style of the `<Cursor />` component.

Therefore I tried to access a function I set up inside my `<Cursor />` component in my `<Item />` component. Unfortunately when hovering it does not update my state and as consequence the style of my `<Cursor />` does not change.

My Cursor component looks like this (simplified):

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
export const CursorContext = React.createContext(false)

class Cursor extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      positionX: 0,
      positionY: 0,
      scrollOffsetY: 0,
      display: "none",
      isHoveringProjectTeaserImage: false,
    }
    this.handleMousePosition = this.handleMousePosition.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseOverProjectTeaser = this.handleMouseOverProjectTeaser.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseLeaveProjectTeaser = this.handleMouseLeaveProjectTeaser.bind(this)
  }

  handleMousePosition = (mouse) => {
    this.setState({
      positionX: mouse.pageX,
      positionY: mouse.pageY,
      display: "block",
      scrollOffsetY: window.pageYOffset
    })
  }

  handleMouseOverProjectTeaser = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHoveringProjectTeaserImage: true
    })
  }

  handleMouseLeaveProjectTeaser = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHoveringProjectTeaserImage: false
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMousePosition)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMousePosition)
  }

  render() {

    const {
      positionX,
      positionY,
      display,
      scrollOffsetY,
      isHoveringProjectTeaserImage
    } = this.state

    return(

    <CursorContext.Provider value={this.state}>
      <div>
        <StyledCursor
          style={ isHoveringProjectTeaserImage
                  ? {backgroundColor: "red", display: `${display}`, top: `${positionY - scrollOffsetY}px`, left: `${positionX}px`}
                  : {backgroundColor: "yellow", display: `${display}`, top: `${positionY - scrollOffsetY}px`, left: `${positionX}px`}}
        />
      </div>
    </CursorContext.Provider>
    )
  }

}

export default Cursor
```

And my Item Component that can be hovered looks like this (simplified):

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { CursorContext } from '../Cursor/Index';

class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // not showing stuff in here that's not relevant
  }

  static contextType = CursorContext

  render() {
    return(
      <CursorContext.Consumer>
        {(value) =>
          <StyledItem
            onMouseOver={value.handleMouseOverProjectTeaser}
            onMouseLeave={value.handleMouseLeaveProjectTeaser}
          >
          </StyledItem>
        }
      </CursorContext.Consumer>
    )
  }

}

export default Item
```

Do I even need to use `static contextType = CursorContext`?

When not passing a default value (I thought they are optional anyway) I am getting an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleMouseOverProjectTeaser' of undefined`, as soon as I pass a long a `false` as default value my App renders but does not update my `<Cursor />` state.

Am I even using Context API correctly?

Comment: "When not passing a default value" not sure which part this refers to

Comment: It refers to having React.createContext(false) vs having React.createContext()

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted for detailed and focused question.

Comment: I found this freat article on context API in functional components https://malikasinger.medium.com/react-context-api-getting-started-d4aeb87363f3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## React.createContext default value?

As you correctly stated, the value passed to `React.createContext()` does not matter in this case.

> When not passing a default value (I thought they are optional anyway) I am getting an TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleMouseOverProjectTeaser' of undefined, as soon as I pass a long a false as default value my App renders but does not update my  state.

This brings out the fact that your default value is always used: try running `undefined.blahblah` vs. `false.blahblah`: the former throws a TypeError while the second silently returns `undefined`.

So we know the value you set in `<Provider value={...}>` never reaches the consumer, but *why?*

## The Context is only available to its descendants

The `<C.Consumer>` is not rendered as a descendant of the `<C.Provider>`, so it can't get access to it. In other words, the provider should "enclose" the consumers. From the docs:

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components [...]

The root of that tree is your `<C.Provider>`, and in your case, the consumer is not part of that tree.

Something like that could work:

```
<CursorContext>
  <StyledCursor />
  <Layout>
    <Content>
      <Item />
    </Content>
  </Layout>
</CursorContext>
```

## Misc.

> Do I even need to use static contextType = CursorContext?

Not really, if you're using `<CursorContext.Consumer>`. From the docs:

> Context.Consumer: A React component that subscribes to context changes.

But in your case, since you don't need to listen to context changes (from your example code anyways),  just keep the `static contextType`:

```
  static contextType = CursorContext

  render() {
    return(
      <StyledItem
        onMouseOver={this.context.handleMouseOverProjectTeaser}
        onMouseLeave={this.context.handleMouseLeaveProjectTeaser}
      >
      </StyledItem>
    )
  }
```

The point is you should use one or the other, **you don't need both**.

---

Last thing, you're passing `this.state` in the provider, and using `this.context.handleMouseOverProjectTeaser` in the child component... but there is no such function in `<Cursor>`'s state. Maybe you intended to pass `<Cursor>` itself, or better, just the handlers?

Comment: Thank you for your extremely detailed and well-explained answer, really appreciated. To be honest I could not find the time to try it, but will let you know.

Again, thank you a ton!

Comment: this article might be helpful https://malikasinger.medium.com/react-context-api-getting-started-d4aeb87363f3