# How to share a React context between two different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

So I am using the Context API from React and have one component called `CreateComposition` that uses the `createContext()` and exports it. I then import it into a component called `Compositions`, and use `useContext()` to display it as a list. However when I use the Link from react router to go between the CreateComposition component and Compositions component, the compositions do not save.

This is the current code I have for both components.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const CompositionsContext = createContext([' No Compositions Currently']);

const CreateComposition = () => {
    const [taal, setTaal] = useState('');
    const [bpm, setBpm] = useState('');
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
  
    const [compositions, setCompositions] = useState([]); 
  
    const sayKayeda = () => {
      alert(taal + " " + bpm + " " + name);
    }
  
    const changeTaal = (event) => {
      setTaal(event.target.value);
    }
  
    const changeBPM = (event) => {
      setBpm(event.target.value);
    }
  
    const changeName = (event) => {
      setName(event.target.value);
    }
  
    const addNewComposition = () => {
      const newComposition = `${taal} ${bpm} ${name}`;
      setCompositions([...compositions, newComposition]);
      setTaal('');
      setBpm('');
      setName('');
    }

    return (
      <CompositionsContext.Provider value={compositions}>
        <h2>Input Kayeda Details Below</h2>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <label><b>Taal</b>&nbsp; 
          <input onChange={changeTaal} value={taal}></input>
        </label>
        <br></br>
        <label><b>BPM</b>&nbsp; 
          <input onChange={changeBPM} value={bpm}></input>
        </label>
        <br></br>
        <label><b>Name</b>&nbsp; 
          <input onChange={changeName} value={name}></input>
        </label>
        <p></p>
        <button onClick={sayKayeda}>Current Kayeda</button>
        &nbsp; 
        <button onClick={addNewComposition}>Add Composition</button>
        <br></br>
        <Link to='/compositions' className='btn'><h2>Compositions</h2></Link>
      </CompositionsContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { CompositionsContext };
export default CreateComposition;
```

Compositions.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CompositionsContext } from './CreateComposition'

//Fix the display
const Compositions = () => {
  const compositions = useContext(CompositionsContext);
  return (
    <CompositionsContext.Provider value={compositions}>
      <Link to='/createcomposition' className='btn'>
        <h1>Create Compositions</h1>
      </Link>
      <p></p>
      <h2>List of Compositions</h2>
      <ul>
        {compositions.map((composition, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{composition}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </CompositionsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Compositions;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the React Context API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401934/how-to-use-the-react-context-api)

Comment: "when I go between the two, they do not save." - Please [edit] to clarify what exactly this statement means, e.g. what exactly you are doing to go between the two components. Just FYI you are using two separate `CompositionsContext.Provider` components, each with their own provided context value. The two do not share any state or logic. You may need to provide a more complete [mcve] so we can see how these two components relate.

Comment: I have edited my message to show that when I use the Link between the two components, the CompositionsContext that I export does not save its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that you are using two ***separate*** `CompositionsContext.Provider` components, so you are providing two separate `CompositionsContext` context values. On top of this, when you navigate away from the route rendering `CreateComposition`, the local `compositions` state is garbage collected, so upon navigating back to `"/createcomposition"` the component mounts anew and the `compositions` state is the initial `[]` value.

## Solution

Rewrite the code to use a single `CompositionsContext.Provider` context provider component such that it is higher in the ReactTree than the components consuming its value, and that it remains mounted while navigating between routes.

Example:

```
const CompositionsContext = createContext([' No Compositions Currently']);

const useCompositions = () => useContext(CompositionsContext);

const CompositionsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [compositions, setCompositions] = useState([]);

  const addNewComposition = (newComposition) => {
    setCompositions(compositions => compositions.concat(newComposition));
  };

  return (
    <CompositionsContext.Provider
      value={{ addNewComposition, compositions }}
    >
      {children}
    </CompositionsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const CreateComposition = () => {
  const { addNewComposition } = useCompositions();

  const [taal, setTaal] = useState('');
  const [bpm, setBpm] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  
  const sayKayeda = () => {
    alert(taal + " " + bpm + " " + name);
  };
  
  const changeTaal = (event) => {
    setTaal(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const changeBPM = (event) => {
    setBpm(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const changeName = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const addNewCompositionHandler = () => {
    const newComposition = `${taal} ${bpm} ${name}`;
    addNewComposition(newComposition);
    setTaal('');
    setBpm('');
    setName('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Input Kayeda Details Below</h2>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <label>
        <b>Taal</b>&nbsp; 
        <input onChange={changeTaal} value={taal} />
      </label>
      <br></br>
      <label>
        <b>BPM</b>&nbsp; 
        <input onChange={changeBPM} value={bpm} />
      </label>
      <br></br>
      <label>
        <b>Name</b>&nbsp; 
        <input onChange={changeName} value={name} />
      </label>
      <p></p>
      <button onClick={sayKayeda}>Current Kayeda</button>
      &nbsp; 
      <button onClick={addNewCompositionHandler}>
        Add Composition
      </button>
      <br></br>
      <Link to='/compositions' className='btn'>
        <h2>Compositions</h2>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Compositions = () => {
  const { compositions } = useCompositions();

  return (
    <>
      <Link to='/createcomposition' className='btn'>
        <h1>Create Compositions</h1>
      </Link>
      <p></p>
      <h2>List of Compositions</h2>
      <ul>
        {compositions.map((composition, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{composition}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<CompositionsContextProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/createcomposition" element={<CreateComposition />} />
    <Route path="/compositions" element={<Compositions />} />
  </Routes>
</CompositionsContextProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use two separate context providers in 2 components.
In this case, each consumer will get context values from a single provider (the nearest provider up the component tree), and no context values are shared between these two components.

And, in Compositions component, you are using useContext. Here, this component or its parent component should be wrapped with context provider, not on render function.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by wrapping with context provider, should that happen with the useContext()?

Comment: @51014 I meant this.
<CompositionsContext.Provider value={compositions}>
  {...}
  <Compositions />
  {...}
</CompositionsContext.Provider>

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same context instance in both components. Since you've exported the CompositionsContext, you can directly use it in the Compositions component without creating a new provider.

```
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/createcomposition" className="btn">
        <h1>Create Compositions</h1>
      </Link>
      <p></p>
      <h2>List of Compositions</h2>
      <ul>
        {compositions.map((composition, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{composition}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```